# When will the Australian Senate vote on the 2014 budget?

Tags: budget, australia, senate

This question is quiet specific.
**When will the Australia Senate debate and vote on the 2014 budget?** 

**Further, where/how can I find out this information in general?**

I assume somewhere a agenda is published.

The 2014 budget is [quiet controversial](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2014-05-13/budget-20143-abbott-government-face-months-of-wrangling-senate/5451140).
It has now been presented to the Lower House, and I assume it has been passed, since the government has absolute majority there. 
The government does not hold a majority of power in the Senate (Upper House). 
They have [threatened a double dissolution,](http://www.smh.com.au/federal-politics/political-news/bill-shorten-dismisses-tony-abbotts-threats-on-calling-another-election-over-the-budget-20140515-zrd58.html) but it is probably empty words, 
so 'horse-trading' will occur, and the budget will likely be rejected by the Senate, 
as the senate can't modify "money" bills. 
Negotiations will be made behind the scenes, it will be modified and repressented to the lower house Passed, and sent back to the senate.

**How can I work out the dates associated with all this?** 
It looks like it can't be happening before July 1st as [this news article](http://www.canberratimes.com.au/comment/new-senators-could-still-block-budget-20140514-zrcn2.html) talks about the new senators who will be sworn in then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Parliamentary [Sitting Calendar](http://www.aph.gov.au/About_Parliament/Sitting_Calendar), the Senate will next sit from June 16 to June 26. (These days are shown in blue, indicating that both houses sit. On green days, only the House of Representatives sits. On pink days, only the Senate sits.)

Newly elected Senators will first sit on July 7 (see the calendar and [s.13](http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/cth/consol_act/coaca430/s13.html) of the Constitution).

The House of Representatives has not sat since the Budget Reply speech (May 15), and its Budget Estimates sittings are due to begin on May 26. Hence, at the time of writing (May 25), I wouldn't think any Budget legislation has yet been passed by the House.